# Unable to change password to sync it with Azure AD

Tags: azure, entra-id

I am following instructions on how to connect my PC up to Azure AD (I do not have a domain server) but when I go to this page:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-ds-getting-started-password-sync/

it states that I need to change my password to sync it all up, but there is no change password option for me when I click on the link: http://myapps.microsoft.com and then click on Profile.

All I have is my profile details, I have no "Change Password" or "Register for Password Reset" option which are shown in the screenshot on that page.

Alternatively, when I go to Start -> Settings -> System -> About -> Join Azure AD and then enter my email address in there it states "Are you sure that's the right email address? This organisation doesn't support joining Azure AD."

Can someone tell me if I've missed something or need to do something more to get this working please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you understand the processes involved here? 
What you are trying to do is sync your local active Directory Domain to Azure AD (copy your users, groups, contacts etc from your internal **Domain-Controller(s)** to Azure AD).

This is not meant to sync individual Computers or local users from such computers to Azure AD

If you are sure you know what you're getting into here's some more information. The domain you mean to sync to Azure AD needs to be registered within your tenant (and probably already verified though I'm not 100% sure about that from the top of my head) and needs to be marked as a federated domain.

Please refer to this page for the prerequisites needed to establish a domain sync: [Prerequisites for Azure AD Connect](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect-prerequisites/)

**Edit: clarification**

The link you posted is a bit misleading. Please make sure that the user you are trying to change the password for is actually in the domain you are managing through AAD. 
Please also do note this text below the last screen of the first section:

> After users have changed their password, the new password will be usable in Azure AD Domain Services shortly. After a few minutes, users can sign in to computers joined to the managed domain using their newly changed password.

Note the **joined to the managed domain** part in there.

The key concept here is the difference between the Azure tenant, which is somewhat like a container for all of your objects, and the domain in Azure Active Directory Services (AAD) which exists inside your Tenant and carries it's own users, groups and so forth.

Comment: Thank you but I'm NOT trying to sync my local active directory domain to Azure because I don't have one.  I want to use the new preview version of Azure Active Directory Domain Services (doesn't need a existing domain controller).

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly you are trying to accomplish. AAD (Azure Active Directory) is normally managed by the Global Administrator of the tenant (possibly your own personal account if you registered the tenant). You create and manage objects within that domain using the Azure Management Interface. Please see [https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-create-users/](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-create-users/) about that process. Please see also my update to my original answer about the link you posted